# error insertar fecha compra carrito en la DB

Tags: php, mysqli, dreamweaver

¿Que valor he de darle a fecha_compra en la opcion de las cadenas de valores para que la inserte correctamente en la base de datos? Ahora me sale todo ceros

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblbasket (idUsuario, idProducto, strNombre, strImagen, intCantidad, dblPrecio, fecha_compra)
SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, 1, dblPrecio, %s FROM tabla_productos  WHERE idProductos = %s",


GetSQLValueString($link, $_GET['recordID'], "date"));

mysqli_select_db($link, $database_db);

 mysqli_free_result($Result1);
?>
```

Comment: Por favor sé un poco mas especifico, por lo que entiendo lo que quieres es guardar la fecha en la que se hizo una compra, pero, ¿esa fecha ya esta guardada en otra tabla o se debe obtener al momento del insert?

Comment: Tienes razón, edité y fui más al grano. Es a la hora de insertar un producto el cliente a su carrito, que aparezca la fecha del día que lo añadió, (que no está guardada en ningún sitio/tabla) pero como primero hay un INSERT y luego se busca en un SELECT donde no hay fecha no se como hacerlo/recogerlo.

Comment: Pero si es así porque no intentas simplemente poner un NOW() a la hora del insert en lugar de buscar la fecha en otra tabla? ¿no te funciona de esa manera?

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que reemplace el atributo fecha_compra en el INSERT por NOW()? Voy a probar y os cuento. Es que no se programar, copió/pego códigos/ejemplo, jejjej.

Comment: Si, basicamente eso te daría la fecha y hora en la cual se realizó cada insert, pero debes tener en cuenta que la fecha y hora de MySQL deben corresponder a tu fecha y hora local, sino igual puedes insertarla desde PHP, prueba y me cuentas.

Comment: Vale, funciona pero va en el SELECT justo antes de FROM, (te entendí tras el INSERT), si lo coloco/reemplazo ahí por fecha_compra me da error SQL.  ¿Es lógico?

Comment: Si, disculpa que no fuese más explícito, quise decir que en el select agregaras el NOW() en el lugar del campo que deseas la fecha y hora, voy a colocar una respuesta y me dices si asi lo estas haciendo.

Comment: Perfecto funciona, gracias @Josue Arriola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agregando un NOW() en el campo que deseas la fecha y hora al momento de hacer el insert, solo debes tener cuidado de que la fecha y hora de MySQL correspondan con tu fecha y hora local, sino igualmente tienes que configurar eso, el insert debería quedar algo asi:

```
INSERT INTO tblbasket (idUsuario, idProducto, strNombre, strImagen, intCantidad, dblPrecio, fecha_compra)
SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, 1, dblPrecio, NOW() FROM tabla_productos  WHERE idProductos = %s
```